# VPC running WinXP SP3 with WAMP: 403 error on network drive

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-xp, http-status-code-403, amazon-vpc

Ok, I have Win7 Ultimate 64bit running VPC. VPC is running WinXP Pro SP3 with WAMP.

I'm using:

1. "Integrated features" to mount my Win7 drives via network.
2. WAMP for my server (yes, as Admin)
3. IE6 and IE8 on the two VPCs (there are two)
4. and thats it!

When I create an alias to point to the network drives it works, but I get 403 errors when I try to hit the alias.

**Alias**:

```
Alias /chemdry/ "\\tsclient\C\public_html\chemdry/" 

<Directory "\\tsclient\C\public_html\chemdry/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any ideas? I'm building a browser testing environment on my Dev machine.

**Log**:

```
[Thu Oct 28 01:32:36 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 28 01:32:36 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Thu Oct 28 01:32:36 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3652
[Thu Oct 28 01:32:37 2010] [notice] Child 3652: Child process is running
[Thu Oct 28 01:32:37 2010] [notice] Child 3652: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Oct 28 01:32:37 2010] [notice] Child 3652: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Oct 28 01:32:37 2010] [notice] Child 3652: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:55 2010] [warn] pid file C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.11/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:55 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:55 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:55 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2564
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:56 2010] [notice] Child 2564: Child process is running
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:56 2010] [notice] Child 2564: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:56 2010] [notice] Child 2564: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:56 2010] [notice] Child 2564: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:59 2010] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu Oct 28 01:39:59 2010] [notice] Child 2564: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Thu Oct 28 01:40:00 2010] [notice] Child 2564: Released the start mutex
[Thu Oct 28 01:40:01 2010] [notice] Child 2564: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Oct 28 01:40:01 2010] [notice] Child 2564: Child process is exiting
[Thu Oct 28 01:40:01 2010] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Thu Oct 28 01:41:29 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 28 01:41:29 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Thu Oct 28 01:41:29 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2988
[Thu Oct 28 01:41:30 2010] [notice] Child 2988: Child process is running
[Thu Oct 28 01:41:30 2010] [notice] Child 2988: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Oct 28 01:41:30 2010] [notice] Child 2988: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Oct 28 01:41:30 2010] [notice] Child 2988: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:48 2010] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:48 2010] [notice] Child 2988: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:49 2010] [notice] Child 2988: Released the start mutex
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:50 2010] [notice] Child 2988: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:51 2010] [notice] Child 2988: Child process is exiting
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:51 2010] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:51 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:51 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:51 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3500
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:52 2010] [notice] Child 3500: Child process is running
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:52 2010] [notice] Child 3500: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:52 2010] [notice] Child 3500: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Oct 28 01:43:52 2010] [notice] Child 3500: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Oct 28 01:44:10 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/chemdry
[Thu Oct 28 01:45:03 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/tsclient
[Thu Oct 28 01:45:15 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/tsclient
[Thu Oct 28 01:45:45 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/tsclient, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu Oct 28 01:53:11 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/tsclient, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu Oct 28 01:57:42 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/tsclient
[Thu Oct 28 01:58:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/tsclient
```

**Links**:

http://blog.mattwoodward.com/accessing-a-network-drive-from-apache-and-tom
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/win_service.html - (see User Account for Apache Service)

**Updates**:

1. I have changed the "login account" for the service from "Local" to .\Kevin (this is an admin account

Comment: the network drive is the c: on win7

Comment: Hmm...why the \\tsclient?

Comment: its a network drive. Should I be using something else?

Comment: So what account exactly is the Apache service running as? It has to run as an account with network privileges in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I need though another question:

[How do I setup a "service account" for apache on XP pro?](https://serverfault.com/questions/195834/how-do-i-setup-a-service-account-for-apache-on-xp-pro)

And, I also decided to use Virtual Hosts instead of a load of alias' and it worked out well :D