# How do I setup a "service account" for apache on XP pro?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-service, http-status-code-403, network-share, service-accounts

**This question has been spawned from this:**

[VPC running WinXP SP3 with WAMP: 403 error on network drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/195675/vpc-running-winxp-sp3-with-wamp-403-error-on-network-drive)

**The real question**:

Basically i need to know how to setup a "service account" that apache can use to access my virtual network drives on a VPC.

```
//tsclient/C/public_html
```

I have changed the service properties; the login account, to my local Admin account "./Kevin". However, this has been noneffective.

I continue to receive `403` errors when I try to access the network with apache.

**Video of setup**:

http://www.screencast.com/users/kevindees/folders/Jing/media/0f551d3b-326f-48bc-a5da-e1ddeb7229fb

Any ideas would be great!

**Links**:

- http://blog.mattwoodward.com/accessing-a-network-drive-from-apache-and-tom-
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/platform/windows.html-

Comment: Just moved to vbox and I'm having the same issues. Will post better video soon.

Comment: added video http://www.screencast.com/users/kevindees/folders/Jing/media/0f551d3b-326f-48bc-a5da-e1ddeb7229fb

Comment: decided to use vh instead of an alias and all is well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a user account, grant it the ability to 'run as a service' and 'act as part of the OS' from the local security policy.  Ensure that that account has permissions to your Apache directories.  Once your service is installed, configure it to run as that user.

Comment: Is it important that I create the account before installing the service?

Comment: No - shouldn't matter, unless the installer gives you the option of specifying the account.

Comment: I thought it was "log in as a service"?

Comment: I was doing it by memory, so the exact phrasing may be different.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. I had added a new user via control panel and computer management. Are there other settings I need to change?

Comment: Since you can't add 'run as a service' and 'act as part of the OS' from the Control Panel, yes, there are more settings you need to apply.  Follow the rest of the steps from the Local Security Policy console

Comment: I also changed the security policies and group. I also have changed the permissions for the whole wamp folder.

Comment: Ok, this is what I have http://www.screencast.com/users/kevindees/folders/Jing/media/0f551d3b-326f-48bc-a5da-e1ddeb7229fb